# How to trim silence from mp3 files, with less than 2 seconds duration, using mp3splt?

Tags: audio, mp3

Can anybody provide a command-line for achieving that goal?

The goal is to remove silence from the start and end of mp3 files with short durations, like less than 2 seconds duration files.

An example mp3 file with silence at the start and end is available here:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv-gP4NyojQoGrC_EAICpOcWTP4

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
mp3splt -r file.mp3
```

Comment: it creates a new file with a suffix in its name, I want to do an in-place trim in the same file, possible? how?